# Multiplay explodes in foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have this API from Yahoo and I want to create Breadcrumb use it:

So xml result is like this:

```
<CategoryPath>Auction > Conputer > PC</CategoryPath>
<CategoryIdPath>0,23336,2084039759</CategoryIdPath>
```

What I want to create is Breadcrumb

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="o">Auction</a></li>
    <li><a href="23336">Conputer</a></li>
    <li><a href="2084039759">PC</a></li>
</ul>
```

Of Course every time it will be different values, so I need to explode them and put this two explodes in one foreach loop. But I don't have any idea how to do it...

Can someone show me how can i do it or show a different approach?

Comment: explode both of them >> array_combine >> loop & output

Comment: @hassan Thank you!!! array_combine

Comment: If you've worked out how to do it, post an answer to tidy up the question.

Comment: @NigelRen done it!

Answer (score 0):

First get arrays:

```
$category_path = explode(' > ', $xml->Result->CategoryPath);
$category_path_id = explode(',', $xml->Result->CategoryIdPath);
```

Then combine them:

```
$breadcrumbs = array_combine($category_path_id, $category_path);
```

Then loop  them(i use Laravel Blade template):

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    @foreach($breadcrumbs as $id => $name)
       <li><a href="?category={{ $id }}">{{ $name }}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```